# Select não replica para todos os itens

Tags: php, jquery-select2, codeigniter-3

Preciso que ao realizar a seleção de uma cidade através de um select, outro select forneça apenas os dados pertinentes a ação.
A exemplo, existe uma tabela sql, que contém alguns produtos, quando seleciono a empresa, preciso que apenas os itens relacionado a ela apareçam no select

tem uma model com o seguinte código

```
function carregagrupotecidos($gt_emp){
    $this->db->select('id_gt, grupotecidos');
    $this->db->from('grupotecidos');       
    $this->db->where('gt_emp', $gt_emp);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

-> o controller

```
function verificagrupotecidos() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) { // valida usuário logado
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $usuarioid = $session_data['UsuarioId'];

        $option = '';

        if ($this->input->post('gt_emp')) {
            $gt_emp = $this->input->post('gt_emp');
            $this->load->model('model_geral');
            $carregagtecidos = $this->model_geral->carregagtecidos($gt_emp);
            if ((isset($carregagtecidos)) && (!empty($carregagtecidos))) {
                foreach ($carregagtecidos as $cg) {
                    $option .= '<option value="' . $cg->id_gt . '">' . $cg->grupotecidos . '</option>';
                }
                echo $option;
            } else {
                $option = '<option>Grupo tecidos não encontrado!</option>';
                echo $option;
            }
        } else {
            $option = '<option>Grupo tecidos não encontrado! Contate o administrador!</option>';
            echo $option;
        }
    } else {
        $option = '<option>SESSÃO EXPIRADA</option>';
        echo $option;
    }
}
```

->a funçao jquery

```
function verificagrupotecidos(gt_emp) {
                                        //debugger;
                                        var url = base_url + "home/verificagrupotecidos";
                                        $.post(url, {gt_emp: gt_emp}, 
                                        function (session_data) {
                                            //document.querySelectorAll("#carregtecidos select");
                                            $('#carregtecidos option').remove();
                                            $('#carregtecidos').append("'<option>--Selecione o Grupo--</option>'");
                                            $('#carregtecidos').append("'" + session_data + "'");
                                        });
```

->abaixo o select onde é realizado o evento

```
<div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="nomeempresa" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Empresa</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="nomeempresa" name="nomeempresa" onchange="verificagrupotecidos(this.value)">
                                                        <option value="">Selecione  a Empresa...</option>
                                                        <?php
                                                        if ((isset($empresas)) && (!empty($empresas))) {
                                                            foreach ($empresas as $empresa) {
                                                                if (!empty($empresa->idempresa)) {
                                                                    echo '<option value="' . $empresa->idempresa . '">' . $empresa->nomeempresa . '</option>';
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

->abaixo o select onde é para ser exibido o resultado

```
<div class="form-group">
                                                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                            <select class="form-control" id="carregagtecidos" name="carregagtecidos" onchange="carregaid(this.value)" style="width: 70px">

                                                                            </select>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
```

ele funciona apenas para um produto, não replica para todos igual a imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Quando dá um append para dentro desses selects está usando o atributo id. Só que o atributo id só pode estar vinculado a um elemento especifico em seu html. Não pude constatar se é isso porque não postou o html do formulário. Use uma classe nos selects com seletor e referencie no seu jquery dessa forma.   $('.carregtecidos').append. Acredito que isso deva resolver!

Comment: editei a pergunta e inseri o código html dos dois selects Rafael Salomão, fiz o teste como disse, funcionou.

Comment: Qual a dúvida agora irmão ? Resolveu ?

Comment: sim, resolvido.